# how to display cart icon in block permanent link

Tags: php, prestashop

I've just started working on `prestashop` so I may be very unclear with the nomenclature of the elements. So I'm sorry if I'm using any unusual name.
I'd installed `prestashop 1.5` and found `block permanent link` in the top
[image: as in prestashop 1.5]

But I would like it to display as
[image: bluenile.com]

Which files I supposed to modify in order to display the above `permanent link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first image, you have two modules at top : blockcurrency and blockpermanent module.
In your second you have an additional third module called blocklanguage.

The cart icon or section you see is actually blockcart module. If you want to move it to the permanentlinks section, then you have to work around with CSS and modules positions.

There is no other good way to do this, but if it is difficult for you to do with simple css and module positions, then you can do it the other way as below:

Blockpermanentlinks module has only some static links, it means you can copy its links in the blockpermanentlinks.tpl file and place them in the cart module tpl file, after that you have to work around with a little bit html and css to achieve your required results.

Hope this will help you.